# Eclipse Map and Reduce Plugin & Hadoop Tutorial

Tags: eclipse, apache, hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I'm brand new to Hadoop and I'm following this Yahoo Tutorial (http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/).  I'm currently trying to configure eclipse and the map and reduce plugin to connect to the virtual machine.  One of the settings I need to configure is the **hadoop.job.ugi**.  It does not appear under the Advanced Settings tab of the plugin.  Without this settings, it seems that the plugin is useless because it cannot connect to the VM.  Any suggestions? I have googled the question various times to no avail.

Also,  does anybody know of any more Hadoop tutorials?  The Yahoo ones seems to be the only one available that starts from a completely beginner perspective.  I was trying to use Cloudera as a starting point, but I struggled to find documentation that was good for a beginner.  Maybe I missed something, their website is not very organized in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to your question about tutorial.. I have seen this question being asked before and had few good answers here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627389/how-to-learn-using-hadoop

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735791/hadoop-examples?rq=1

I haven't used Yahoo plugin so with respect to your question on Yahoo plugin issue, I will let someone else answer but I would like to add that if you are just starting on hadoop you can do what I did. I started of by installing hadoop on local computer, worked through some examples on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=hadoop%20mapreduce%20eclipse&oq=hadoop%20mapreduce%20eclipse&gs_l=youtube.3...1824.2914.0.3138.7.7.0.0.0.0.241.811.4j1j2.7.0...0.0...1ac.1.11.youtube.wj9TdCz0hmU). :)

Answer (score 0):

For those who are getting started with Hadoop, I had been accumulating some of the best resources on my blog [here](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/p/hadoopresources.html) around Big Data. There are also a couple of [getting started](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/search/label/gettingstarted) tutorials.